# Нужно выбрать категорию теста и начать прохождение

Tags: c#, winforms, access

Есть форма "Меню тестов", в ней таблица из Access "Тесты" реализованная через DataGridView.Нужно выбрать из таблицы тест и нажать на кнопку "Начать тест" после чего пользователя перенесет в формы исполнения теста, Не понимаю как это реализовать, искал на сайтах нету такой информации... [image]

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084976/datagridview-get-current-selected-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не видя того, что у вас уже есть, сложно посоветовать как вам двигаться дальше, но общая идея такова: по нажатию на кнопку получаете значение выделенной ячейки, далее подгружаете нужный тест, создаете новое окно и отображаете в нем необходимые данные.
[Про работу с DataGridView можно почитать в MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms)

Comment: Можете подробнее рассказать про нажатие кнопки и значение выделенной ячейки,пожалуйста

Comment: @Freshmathick, вам необходимо изучить работу с элементами управления. Про DataGridView можете почитать по ссылке, приведенной в ответе. Про кнопки здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/button-control-windows-forms. Если вкратце: в обработчике события "Щелчок левой кнопки мыши" кнопки получаете данные из DataGridVie.